# How to know if a number is quartic residue or nonresidue modulo n?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I'm writing a program to calculate quadratic residue of a number and for prime number it is mentioned that if p mod 8 equals 5 then there two ways to calculate x (check the pic). the part that I don't understand is it says if a is quartic residue mod n. How are we supposed to know if a is quartic residue or nonresidue?
for example: x^2 = 3296748 mod 3409573 ? how do you know if 3296748 is a quartic residue?
[The formula mentioned in wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3IpP.png)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_or_prime_power_modulus

Comment: This must be the worst possible way imaginable to determine whether $x$ is a quadratic residue. The quickest way to do that is to use Quadratic Reciprocity. Of course you may also calculate $x^{\frac{p-1}2}$ modulo $p$, and see whether the result is $+1$ (yes it’s a residue) or $-1$ (no it isn’t).

Comment: do you mean *quartic* or *quadratic*?

Comment: Check picture please it says quartic

Comment: Lubin I want to find x and based on legrend if my prime mod 8 is 5 then I have two ways to calculate x. I don't know what does quartic residue mean! So I don't know with which one of them I should calculate x!

Comment: Rather than just a picture absent of all context, could you please give a reference to what it is you are quoting/citing? Where did you take that picture from? What page from Wikipedia? What you posted is utterly useless: it lacks absolutely all context. Did you hope we would read your mind? The government hates it when I do that without a properly issued judicial warrant.

Comment: Sorry Arturo I shared the page and the part

Comment: That section is about *finding* the square roots, not detecting whether they are quadratic residues or not. And if you are trying to find the root, then you don’t actually have to figure out whether $a$ is a biquadratic residue or not! Compute $a^{(n+3)/4}$ to see if that is equal to $n$. If it is, then $\pm a^{n+3}/8$ are the square roots, and you know that $a$ is a biquadratic residue mod $n$. If not, then the square root is $\pm a^{(n+3)/8}2^{(n-1)/4}$. Both computations are easy to do by doubling.